# Spring RestTemplate is not preserving accent characters

Tags: spring, solr, character-encoding, urlencode, non-ascii-characters

I have been trying to use accent characters in URL to call SOLR. 
My Url looks like this:

```
    "http://host:8983/solr/principal/select?q=**name:%22Michaël.e%22**"
```

When fire the URL from browser I get the correct result but when try from RestTempalte.exchange(URI,HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class)
The  log I see on SOLR is showing the accent characters being coverted to "?" as shown below

**q=(name:"Micha?.e")**

I have set RestTemple request charSet to "UTF-8" it still does the same.

My SOLR is running on Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to encode HTML characters before calling RestTemplate using [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
String baseUri = "http://host:8983/solr/principal/select?q=**name:%22";
// TODO get name from somewhere
String name = "Michaël.e";
String encodedName= = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

RestTempalte.exchange(baseUri + encodedName + "%22**",HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It converts to some funny characters **name:%22Micha&euml;l.e%22**

Comment: Sorry, I meant URLEncoder, not StringEscapeUtils, which is escaping HTML special characters.